# Convert JSON value in single row in TSQL 2019

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, open-json

I need help in transforming a string to json to put the values in separated lines.
Using tsql (2019)

How do I have to transform the provided data (payload) into a json to create the expected result or is there another way to splitt the data?

Thank you in advanced.

AS for the main keys it works but I would like to have the interests in separated lines as well
current result:

| CustomerID | payload | payload_json | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | {diet:[vegetarian],interest:[cooking,fitness,technology,interior,diy,talk,gaming,fashion]} | {"diet":["vegetarian"],"interest":["cooking","fitness","technology","interior","diy","talk","gaming","fashion"]} | diet | vegetarian |
| 10001 | {diet:[vegetarian],interest:[cooking,fitness,technology,interior,diy,talk,gaming,fashion]} | {"diet":["vegetarian"],"interest":["cooking","fitness","technology","interior","diy","talk","gaming","fashion"]} | interest | ["cooking","fitness","technology","interior","diy","talk","gaming","fashion"] |

Expected Result:

| CustomerID | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | diet | vegetarian |
| 10001 | interest | Cooking |
| 10001 | interest | fitness |
| 10001 | interest | technology |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |

Comment: What's the relevance of `payload`if it's not valid JSON? `value` does not seem to be valid JSON? Which of these columns do you actually want to parse, please explain the logic? And why does row 2 only have three JSON values parsed out?

Comment: the "simple" payload - field is what i got and payload_json is what I have created by using some replace-statements.
The two lines is the result of the previous amendments I performed. 
And now I am stuck and would like to have the values of the second line in separated lines too.

Comment: So why have you stopped at only three rows for the second sample row? Shouldn't it be six?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just want a dynamic `OPENJSON` call.

```sql
SELECT
  t.CustomerID,
  t.[key],
  j.value
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.payload_json, '$.' + t.[key]) j;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/D8_bDEmW)

What the relevance of the `payload` and `value` columns are to the question I don't know, your logic is not clear.

Comment: Payload is the source, Payload_json is my temporary result. 
and instead of multiple lines for the key "interest" I have all interests in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little replace thing:

```sql
SELECT  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(payload, '{', '{"'), ':', '":'), '[', '["'), '],', ']$'), ',', '","'), ']', '"]'), ']$', '],"')
FROM    (
    VALUES  (10001, N'{diet:[vegetarian],interest:[cooking,fitness,technology,interior,diy,talk,gaming,fashion]}')
) t (CustomerID,payload)
```

This converts the payload column into a json which you can use together with openjson.

The replace won't work if you have embedded "," etc, but for simple values it might be good enough. You oughtta get rid of this weird format and use json right away though